# Flutter loading custom list from Hive on application start failing with type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List?' in type cast

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I created a custom class in Hive:

```
@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class GeocodeLocationGoogleItem {
  @HiveField(0)
  String formattedAddress;
  @HiveField(1)
  String lat;
  @HiveField(2)
  String lng;
  @HiveField(3)
  DateTime lastUpdate;
  @HiveField(4)
  HourlyForcastWeatherbit hourlyForcast;

  GeocodeLocationGoogleItem(this.formattedAddress, this.lat, this.lng,
      this.lastUpdate, this.hourlyForcast);
}
```

I then store a list of these like so:

```
  void saveLocationsToMemory() async {
    //open box
    var box = await Hive.openBox<List<GeocodeLocationGoogleItem>>('weatherBox');

    //update list to storage
    box.put('weatherLocationList', weatherLocations);
  }
```

When I close my app and try and restart it I have it load all my adapters:

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(GeocodeLocationGoogleItemAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(HourlyForcastWeatherbitAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(HourlyDataWeatherbitAdapter());
```

Then in my initState for my widget I have:

```
Provider.of<Settings>(context, listen: false).loadLocationsFromMemory();
```

When that runs I receive this error and my list is not loaded:

> E/flutter (23601): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)]
> Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type
> 'List?' in type cast E/flutter (23601): #0
> BoxImpl.get (package:hive/src/box/box_impl.dart:44:26) E/flutter
> (23601): #1      Settings.loadLocationsFromMemory
> (package:dont_forget_the_weather/provider/settings_class.dart:66:28)
> E/flutter (23601):  E/flutter (23601):

When I look at line 66 of settings.loadLocationsFromMemory I have this line:

```
weatherLocations = box.get("weatherLocationList", defaultValue: [])!;
```

The entire method looks like this:

```
void loadLocationsFromMemory() async {
    var box = await Hive.openBox<List<GeocodeLocationGoogleItem>>('weatherBox');

    weatherLocations = box.get("weatherLocationList", defaultValue: [])!;

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: What is the original `weatherLocations`?

Comment: Also, what happens if you remove the  Bang (`!`)  from `box.get("weatherLocationList", defaultValue: [])!`?

Comment: First initialize the list with empty brackets so that it doesn't return null

When you fetch data from database you can update the list

Make sure that updated list is not null by checking with if condition if(newdata != null) {do update the list}

Comment: I think my issues is my list alos has a list of custom objects...

Comment: Try this way, 
weatherLocations = box.get("weatherLocationList", defaultValue: []) ?? [];

Comment: @MendelG and  I think I fixed it. See answer below. Unfortunatley it only works on my emulated android device and not my real one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO after playing around I was able to kind of fox this with slight changes to my saving and loading to hive:

```
 void saveLocationsToMemory() async {
    //open box
    var box = await Hive.openBox<GeocodeLocationGoogleItem>('weatherBox');
    box.clear();
    //update list to storage
    for (var i = 0; i < weatherLocations.length; i++) {
      print(i);
      box.add(weatherLocations[i]);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void loadLocationsFromMemory() async {
    var box = await Hive.openBox<GeocodeLocationGoogleItem>('weatherBox');

    weatherLocations = box.values.toList();

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

The odd thing is that this works on my emulator but does not work on my actual cell phone when I load it on my android device...It will not load.